# Does a continuum exist in reality?

Tags: mathematics

There are uncountably infinite sets in mathematics.
Such as the number of points in the interval [0,1]

Or the set of all integer sequences.

Do these have a physical reality?

In case this helps : for sets you can read physical quantities: Does time exist as a continuum or space or or mass(when seen in light of relativity.)

Comment: Actually there a [countable number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountablyInfinite.html) of infinite sets.

Comment: What do you mean by those sets "having a physical reality"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind does a continuum exist in universe ie does an uncountable infinite set exist in nature...or is it merely a mathematical construction.

Comment: Does physics concern itself with the cardinality of sets? No. It doesn't even concern itself with sets.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well asked. Wherever you try to find a continuum in nature, you will fail. An edge is a geometric abstraction, in reality there are atoms in a more or less geometric pattern. Energy is quantised in photons. So matter and energy are quantised. What about time? Don't know. The only thing I know is that we could measure time only in portions. So every event is quantised for us too.